# org-mode document structure / templates

Tags: org-mode

Suppose you had a large org document of recipes, with hundreds of entries like this:

```
* Tasty Pudding
** Ingredients
- Milk
- Sugar
- Eggs
- Flavorings
** Process
1. Mix the eggs and sugar
2. Heat up the milk and flavorings
3. Temper the milk into the egg mixture
4. Cook the pudding
** Description
It's my favorite pudding
```

But then you realize the description subheading is pointless and your recipes should be structured more like

```
* Tasty Pudding
It's still my favorite pudding, but it makes more
sense to have the description up here!
** Ingredients
...
** Process
...
** Notes
Here's my new additional thoughts about this
pudding.
```

Is it possible to either edit all of these entries at once, or ideally have some kind of "node" structure that these recipes are bound to?

So for example, I could see having a Yas Snippet like:

```
* $1
$2
** Ingredients
- $3
** Process
1. $4
** Notes
$5
```

But of course that would only work for your new recipes, it can't fix the old ones.

Comment: The general approach to this kind of problem is to use `org-map-entries` to walk through the interesting entries (in your case, the top-level entries), passing it a function to do the transformation you require (get the text of the second-level Description entry, delete the entry and copy the text at the top). But this is only a bare-bones comment of how to do it, so there is some significant amount of Lisp programming you would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I defined a macro.

- At the beginning of the document and start the macro (<kbd>F3</kbd>),
- Search (<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) for the string `* Description` (I hope you don't have another structure with name starting with Description) and hit enter (<kbd>RET</kbd>),
- Move the section up twice, (<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> x 2)
- Go to the beginning of the line (<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and kill it (<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>),
- End the macro (<kbd>F4</kbd>),
- Select the buffer (<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) and apply the macro (<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> apply-macro-to-region-lines <kbd>RET</kbd>)